# Win 10 + new Switch: Cant find rest of network

Tags: windows-10, home-networking

Home network, worked fine last year. Upgraded all PCs to Win 10. AND I just had to replace a switch. Now parts of the network no longer see other parts. I am convinced this is a Win 10 problem and not a router or switch problem.

Network looks like this: Router, R1, [wireless, Netgear] connects to Internet and is gateway for all other devices on net; Also has a NAS [USB hard drive attached]. R1 connects to switch 1. Which connects to Switch 2 [S2] which is new Linksys SE1500. two desktops: D1 & D2 connect to S2. Laptop [L3] connects wireless to R1. All machines are Win 10 with latest updates. All machines same Workgroup and same Homegroup. D1 can see D2 [and the Internet] but nothing else. D2 can see D1, L3 and the Internet but not NAS. L3 can see NAS and Internet and D2 but not D1.

The router is IP address: 192.168.1.1; S1 is 192.168.1.2; the new switch S2 has ip address 10.0.0.1 hardwired, no interface to get in and change it. L3 is 192.168.1.107; D1 is 10.0.0.3 and D2 is 10.0.0.4

D1 must be the problem: The NAS works for L3; D2 and L3 work so its not the new switch. nor is it a pass through problem through S1.

D1 is visible on the network; is willing to share files, music etc. says it is on private network 3 while L3 says its on a different network.

Any ideas what to tweak, rights, parameters ??

Comment: You may want to try disabling Windows Firewall on the Win10 machines and see if your network becomes fully visible to all clients... then start re-introducing it...?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add a comment because I need 50 reputation. So I'll post here.
Jmorgie7, I don't think it is a Windows issue but rather a network problem. 
It's indeed weird who can see what in your network, but could you put your two desktops in the 192.168.1.0 network? If the S2 is just a switch and not a router then that 10.0.0.1 is just a management IP? Also, the usb attached NAS, how do you access it? Is it mounted on your 192.168.1.1 router?

Comment: thanks for the ideas;  i had disabled win firewall to no effect.  the NAS looks like a server:  \\readyshare\ at ip 192.168.1.1   i am thinking i need to rebuild the network starting at the router.

Comment: Here is a link about the management of your switch. It's a management vlan IP and you can change it. It's explained here: http://www.linksys.com/my/support-article?articleNum=137590.
Start at point 6. Type http://10.0.0.1 in your browser and you should see a login screen. This will not resolve your network problem though. To try resolving that, start placing all hosts in the 192.168.1.0 network. That could be a good start.